# Post an entity with Spring Data REST which has relations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data Rest. I have a problem trying to POST an object with association(e.g. address is a field in my entity that is mapped as many to one).

The question is, what format should we use to connect our new entity with its relations. I saw several answers and tried all options that I found. Unfortunately, all of them don't work for me. 
The following error happens:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ADDRESS_ID"; SQL statement:
```

JSON that I tried:

```
{
"name": "test",
"email": "test@email",
"address": "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/address/1"
}
```

Also tried these:

```
"address": {"id":"http://localhost:8080/MyApp/address/1"}
```

And this:

```
"address":{"id":1}
```

And even this:

```
"address": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/address/1"
}
```

Is there a way to do this, or only writing own implementation of controller for POST? Thanks!

Comment: Post your entities.

Comment: What statements are in DB? You are obviously generating an insert

Comment: Yes, it's POST and insert statement. The address object exists, I need to create a new object of another entity where address is just an association.

Comment: Here, https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/halprimer I can see that it's said that we need to use just IDs. But API should resolve it. However, it's just HAL itself. Spring could have done it differently.

Comment: If I POST to URL that starts with:
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/address/1/persons/
I don't need to specify it in request and it works. However, that doesn't help. Since I want to use the end-point that looks like I provided above.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have a model like this:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    //..
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
    //..
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    //..
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    //..
}
```

then you can POST a new `User` with its `addresses` like this:

```json
POST http://localhost:8080/api/users
{
    "name" : "user1",
    "addresses" : [
        "http://localhost:8080/api/addresses/1",
        "http://localhost:8080/api/addresses/2"
        ]
}
```

Before POST a new User, addresses ID#1 and ID#2 must be already persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if user has Address as not a collection? e.g. private Address address; ?

Comment: @dvelopp use the same technics: `"address": "http://localhost:8080/api/addresses/1"` (don't forget to accept/upvote my answer if it helped you).

Comment: Doesn't work still. Maybe something with my overall structure. Says ID has not been found.
"address": "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/address/1"

Comment: @dvelopp see my working [examples](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo)...

Comment: Thanks. There are a lot of useful examples here. 
It seems I need to investigate PagedResourcesAssembler and make some conclusions. Before that I will use as I mentioned before " 
If I POST to URL that starts with: localhost:8080/MyApp/address/1/persons I don't need to specify it in request and it works. However, that doesn't help. Since I want to use the end-point that looks like I provided above. – dvelopp yesterday  "

Comment: https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example5/QuestionController.java
In this example you use hateoas. I just think, if there is a way to do the same but with hateoas? I mean, to get associated entities in the post request? Or it's just Spring Data Rest feature.

Comment: @dvelopp Sorry I didn't understand what do you mean.. It was an answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44295231)

Comment: I know this is an old thread but this answer doesn't seem to work, can you take a look at my example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415740/can-only-create-association-from-one-side-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: i get this error ```Cannot construct instance of   (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ``` with your method

Comment: May I know where i can reference this in Spring documentations? Is this a Spring Web Mvc feature or a Spring Data Rest feature?

Comment: Why would the URIs not appear as the `href` property within `_links`? This doesn't seem to line up with HAL and the Spring Data Rest responses.

Comment: Your Problem could be that you forgor to manually handle the bidirectional relation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464782/how-to-maintain-bi-directional-relationships-with-spring-data-rest-and-jpa