# Sprint boot: POST an entity with a foreign key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, foreign-keys

I am playing around with Spring boot and I am trying to post an entity that has foreign keys

Example: product (id,code, description, category) and category(id, category)
To post a product i would post `{"code":"123","description":"bananas"}`

How would I specify the category?
`{"code":"123","description":"bananas","category":1}` doesn't seem to work

I saw a post here relating to Spring Data that sugested using the URI of the primary table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497114/post-an-entity-with-spring-data-rest-which-has-relations

is there a simpler way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to specify category as json object like below

```
 {"code":"123","description":"bananas","category": { "id" : 1}}
```

Comment: Tks, It worked, however i had to remove JsonIgnore. Is there any way to make it work and also not include the primary table on the product json?