# Can only create association from one side in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-rest

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    //..
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<File> files;
    //..
}

@Entity
public class File {
    //..
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = true)
    Product product;
    //..
}
```

I can only create the association from one side so

```
POST /files/{id}
{    
    "product" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1"
}
```

works but

```
POST /products/{id}
{    
    "files" : [
        "http://localhost:8080/api/files/1"
        ]
}
```

doesn't work. The POST doesn't return any error but the association is not made and the db doesn't update the foreign key.

According to this question [Post an entity with Spring Data REST which has relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497114/post-an-entity-with-spring-data-rest-which-has-relations) it should work, but it doesn't.

---

EDIT: Added additional example page from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

Even in that sample page you can see that association can ever only be made from the "many" side. In that example, he made a Library<->Books One-To-Many relationship and the only you can make association is as follows:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list"
-d "http://localhost:8080/libraries/1" http://localhost:8080/books/1/library
```

You cannot POST to http://localhost:8080/libraries/1

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that bi-directional one-to-many is not supported by SDR now, unfortunately.

I've [just tried](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-data-rest-demo-2020.04) to use uni-directional one-to-many and it's [working ok](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-data-rest-demo-2020.04/blob/master/demo-api.http):

Entities:

```java
@Entity
class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/parents
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "parent1",
  "children": [
    "http://localhost:8080/children/1"
  ]
}
```

Result:

```sql
insert into parent (name, id) values ('parent1', 2);
insert into parent_children (parent_id, children_id) values (2, 1);
```

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean? Does it work in this case only because Child does not reference to Parent?

Comment: @erotsppa Practically. Bidirectional one-to-many is different from the unidirectional one that associated entity doesn't have a reference to the first one. And a bidirectional OTM is a little harder to implement due to the necessity of synchronizing both ends of the association. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30474303) you can find a recommendation of the SDR author Oliver Drotbohm about not using the Bidirectional OTM...