# Using Spring Data Rest POST for linking

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I'm creating a user registration form in `React`. My backend is `Spring Data Rest`. The registration form has `firstName`, `lastName`, `username`, `city` & `country` fields. `city` & `country` fields are standard list so they come from `city` & `country` tables.

In a regular Java MVC application, we would post the details like `"firstName=Scot&lastName=Taylor&username=scot_taylor&city=45&country=32"` at `/registration` url which will be collected at the Spring Controller in the following DTO.

```
public class UserDetailDto {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName,
    private String username;
    private Long city;   // primary key for city table
    private Long country; // primary key for city table

    // skipped other code like getter/setter
}
```

This DTO will then be passed to `registration service`. The `registration service` will load city & country entities, associate to new `User` entity and save into the database.

Reading the spring data rest documentation it appears, I need to perform following 3 HTTP calls.

1. `POST:` to save User. `/users`
2. `PUT:` to update city relation `/users/1/city`
3. `PUT:` to update country relation `/users/1/country`

How can I implement the same in one api call with spring data rest & react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to POST in a single call. Obviously the city and country must exist before the call.

In your instance I would expect the payload to be as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/users
{
    "firstName" : "Joe",
    "lastName" : "Bloggs",
    "userName" : "user1",
    "city" : "http://localhost:8080/api/cities/1",
    "country" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/1"
}
```

Comment: Yes that's possible but with the controller/service pattern. But how can we do it in a single transaction. Because say first call to save user passes but 2nd call to associate city fails. Then we will have incomplete User record in the database. With the regular MVC application and the DTO pattern, we save transaction. So if something fails everything is rolled back. My question was how spring data rest solves this problem?

Comment: Do you mean we will have to write a custom controller/service for this case?

Comment: No, you don't have to write a custom controller/service for this case. Have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497114/post-an-entity-with-spring-data-rest-which-has-relations. I am going to update answer to remove errors.