# Wrong Header of the API versioning of the Post Request does not come to handleNoHandlerFoundException?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

I am using `Spring Boot v2.1.7 + HATEOAS + Spring Rest + Spring Security`. When consumer doesn't pass the correct **Custom Header** in the request, say passes X-Accept-Version=v5, it gives me below error.

Error:

```
2020-03-26 15:44:48.201 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/employee-catalog-api/reference-types", parameters={}
2020-03-26 15:44:48.216 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-03-26 15:44:48.217 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.c.d.m.p.s.SAMLUserIdentityServiceImpl : Trying to get UserId from Security Context
2020-03-26 15:44:48.224 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-03-26 15:44:48.234 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-03-26 15:44:48.234 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5c85f23b
2020-03-26 15:44:48.234 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

2020-03-26 15:44:48.254 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-03-26 15:44:48.254 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-03-26 15:44:48.258 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-03-26 15:44:48.258 DEBUG [employee-service,14c23adbe2664530,14c23adbe2664530,false] 3608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/employee-types", headers = {X-Accept-Version=v1})
public ResponseEntity<Integer> saveEmployeeType(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDto employeeDto) {
    .....
    ......
    ......
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Why its not coming to handleNoHandlerFoundException of the @ControllerAdvice ?

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    ...................

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, error, getHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by taking a reference from : [How to set default value of exported as false in rest resource spring data rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295231/how-to-set-default-value-of-exported-as-false-in-rest-resource-spring-data-rest).

By adding below logic, it works greatly.

```
@Component
public class SpringRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED);
        config.setExposeRepositoryMethodsByDefault(false);
    }
}
```